# Haskell 99 questions #10: strange behaviour of '\' symbol

Tags: haskell, literals

So far I have my 99.hs file:

```
import Data.List

myEncode :: Eq a => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
myEncode = map (\x -> (length x, head x)) . group
```

But when trying to use it in *ghci*, I get this (haven't found an explanation yet, though I tried):

```
*Main> myEncode "///aaaaabbbbbbbccdddddxxyyzz0"
[(3,'/'),(5,'a'),(7,'b'),(2,'c'),(5,'d'),(2,'x'),(2,'y'),(2,'z'),(1,'0')]                           │
*Main> myEncode "\\\aaaaabbbbbbbccdddddxxyyzz0"
[(1,'\\'),(1,'\a'),(4,'a'),(7,'b'),(2,'c'),(5,'d'),(2,'x'),(2,'y'),(2,'z'),(1,'0')]
```

Any link to an exhaustive source about this (concerning haskell, of course) will be good, also as a good explanation of this issue.

Comment: ` \ ` is used in strings to escape certain things (like newlines ` \n ` , tabs ` \t ` and so on - to get the actual ` \ ` character you have to escape this with the double-` \\ ` that should explain why you did get what you got - or so I hope )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of escape codes for characters which are hard to type on a normal keyboard or would make Haskell annoying to read in an editor. Thus, for example, the tab character is represented in Haskell code as `'\t'`, the newline by `'\n'`, and so forth. To represent a literal backslash, one escapes it, thus `'\\'`; and `'\a'` happens to be an escape character as well (for the bell control character, an inelegant remnant of a less civilized age).

So the string `"\\\a"` represents a two-character list, containing the backslash character in its first element and the bell control character in its second element.

A full description of the syntax for character and string literals is given in [the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-200002.6).

Comment: Just some kind of confusion because i'm quite new to Haskell and thought that this symbol in a string means itself, but it's not.
Thanks for an explanation and a link to a useful source!

Comment: @id_yulian The backslash escape convention has been adopted by a very large number of programming languages, so it's not just a Haskell issue.

Comment: @Ben now I see it. Maybe haskell  itself is hard-to-understand in the beginning and my brain is overheated) I guess (the more I learn and understand), I won't ask such blunt questions in future.

Comment: @id_yulian No, please do ask questions, blunt or otherwise! (After checking for existing ones, etc). I just wanted to make sure that if you'd never seen backslash escapades before you didn't just file this away as a quirk of Haskell, only to be surprised again in some other language.